# MySQL stored procedures out variable as array

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have MySQL procedure where I want to get a result of query:

```
SELECT id FROM mbus_clients WHERE second_name like surnamePart AS
```

So it should be an array. The decision I've found in the internet is to use temporary table. 
But how can I return a table and read with PHP? Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the procedure:

```
CALL procedurename();
```

If the procedure performs a `SELECT`, the result set of the procedure call will be the same as if you'd performed the query itself. You can then fetch the rows using PHP the same way as if you'd performed a `SELECT`.

Comment: But i should use the first element of this array in procedure. Actually it should return two output variables and both should be array. Is it possible?

Comment: There's no such thing as arrays in MySQL.